# How many non-negative solutions for $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 40$ where $2 \leq x_{1} \leq 8, x_{2} \leq 4, x_{3} \geq 4, x_{4} \leq 5$?

Tags: combinatorics

My solution:

We have:
$x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 40$ where $2 \leq x_{1} \leq 8, x_{2} \leq 4, x_{3} \geq 4, x_{4} \leq 5$

$\Leftrightarrow  x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 40 - x_{1} \quad (*)$

Consider:

$x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 40 - x_{1}$ where $x_{2} \geq 0, x_{3} \geq 4, x_{4} \geq 0 \quad (**)$

$x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 40 - x_{1}$ where $x_{2} \geq 5, x_{3} \geq 4, x_{4} \geq 6 \quad (***)$

Let $f$ is the function that compute the number of non-negative solutions of an equation.

$\implies f(*) = f(**) - f(***)$

Thus, the number of non-negative solutions of (*) is $\sum_{x_{1} = 2}^{8}( {40 - x_{1} + 3 - 1  \choose 3 - 1} - {25-x_{1}+3 - 1 \choose 3 - 1}) = 3045$

I found that the right answer is 210 by trying some programming script. But I don't know what was wrong with my solution. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: The three upper limits on $x_1, x_2, x_4$ and that the only variable not upper restrained is dependent on the three restrained makes the stars and bars/choose solution too restrained to be relevent.  Do this as pure choose/multiplying.  There are so many chooses an the three restrained variables, and the unrestrained can be set up to be completely dependent on the other three.  So it is straight mulitplication

Comment: YOu are *way* over counting.  You have the solution for  $x_2<  5$ OR $x_4< 5$.  You don't want that you want AND.  ANd you also never take $x_3 \ge 4$ into account.  The first term should be $36$ not $40$.

Comment: @fleablood thank for your comment, this is my wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x_1 + x_2 + x_4 \le 8  + 4 + 5 = 17$ so $x_3=40 - x_1 + s_2 + x_4 \ge 40 -17 \ge 4$ so we can ignore the restriction on $x_3$.

$2 \le x_1 \le 6$ so there are $7$ values that $x_1$ can be, $x\le 4$ so there are $5$ values it can be. $x_4 \le 5$ so there are $6$ values it can be and $x_3$ must be $40 - x_1 - x_2 -x_4$ there is only one option dependant on the other three options.

So there $7*5*6 = 210$ options.

Your solution dosn't take $x_3 \ge 4$ into account (which you can be seting it up so that the some is $36$ and not $40$-- I haven't done the math to figure it out but that will lower you answer significantly.  Also by subtracting you are removing the cases with both $x_2 \ge 5$ and $x_4 \ge 6$ but not removing the cases where one or the other is.)

I think to fix your problem using inclusion exclusion you'd want

$\sum_{x_1=2}^8({{40 - 4 -x_1 + 3-1}\choose {3-1}} - {{40 - 4-5 -x_1 + 3-1}\choose {3-1}}-{{40 - 4-6 -x_1 + 3-1}\choose {3-1}}+{{40 - 4 -5-6-x_1 + 3-1}\choose {3-1}})=$

And I'm too lazy to finish.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
A ***General Method***:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{x_{1} = 2}^{8}
\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{4}\sum_{x_{3} = 4}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{4} = 0}^{5}
\bracks{z^{40}}z^{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4}}} =
\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{6}
\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{4}\sum_{x_{3} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{4} = 0}^{5}
\bracks{z^{30}}z^{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{30}}\pars{\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{6}z^{x_{1}}}
\pars{\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{4}z^{x_{2}}}
\pars{\sum_{x_{3} = 0}^{\infty}z^{x_{3}}}
\pars{\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{5}z^{x_{4}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{40}}{1 - z^{7} \over 1 - z}\,{1 - z^{5} \over 1 - z}\,{1 \over 1 - z}\,{1 - z^{6} \over 1 - z}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{40}}\pars{-z^{18} + z^{13} + z^{12} + z^{11} - z^{7} - z^{6} - z^{5} + 1}\pars{1 - z}^{-4}
\\[5mm] = &\
-{-4 \choose 22} - {-4 \choose 27} + {-4 \choose 28} -
{-4 \choose 29} + {-4 \choose 33} - {-4 \choose 34} +
{-4 \choose 35} + {-4 \choose 40}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\ \underbrace{25 \choose 22}_{\ds{2300}}\ +\
\underbrace{30 \choose 27}_{\ds{4060}}\ +\
\underbrace{31 \choose 28}_{\ds{4495}}\ +\
\underbrace{32 \choose 29}_{\ds{4960}}\ -\
\underbrace{36 \choose 33}_{\ds{7140}}\ -\
\underbrace{37 \choose 34}_{\ds{7770}}\ -
\\[2mm] &\ -
\underbrace{38 \choose 35}_{\ds{8436}} +\
\underbrace{43 \choose 40}_{\ds{12341}} = \bbx{\large 210}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

It's the coefficient of $x^{40}$ of the product polynomial

$$(x^2+x^3+x^4 +x^5 + x^6 + x^7 + x^8)(1+x^1+x^2+x^3 +x^4)(x^4 + x^5 + \ldots)(1+x^1+x^2+x^3 +x^4 + x^5)$$

Or equivalently the coefficient of $x^{34}$ of

$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 +x^5 + x^6 )(1+x^1+x^2+x^3 +x^4)(1 + x + x^2 + \ldots)(1+x^1+x^2+x^3 +x^4 + x^5)$$

which can be found using (generalised) binomials etc.

Comment: Isn't this just rephrasing the problem?

Comment: @Christoph just giving an alternative path.

Answer (score 2):

## Math answer

Note that the given constraints for $x_1, x_2$ and $x_4$ and $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^4 x_i = 40$ allows us to define
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_3 &= 40 - x_1 - x_2 - x_4 \\
&\ge 40 - 8 - 4 - 5 \\
&= 23.
\end{aligned}$$
This renders the constraint $x_3 \ge 4$ *redundant*.  As a result, the required answer is $(8-2+1) \times (4+1) \times (5+1) = 210$.

---

## Julia Programming Script

```
x1 = 2:8
x2 = 0:4
x4 = 0:5
x3 = [40 - i - j - k for i in x1 for j in x2 for k in x4]
println(minimum(x3))  # returns 23
println(length(x3))   # returns 210
```

Test [this script on Tutorial's Point](http://tpcg.io/TTB2uM)'s online compiler.